# Intuition of the distribution of the minimum of exponential random variables

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question

Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables with exponential distribution with parameters $a$ and $b$ respectively. It is known (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables)) that $Z:=\min\{X,Y\}$ is exponential distributed with parameter $a+b$ and
$$
I:=P(X\leq Y)=\frac{a}{a+b},\ \ J:=P(Y\leq X)=\frac{b}{a+b}.
$$
One can of course calculate using double integrals to get $I$ and $J$. Would anybody come up with any intuition why $I$ and $J$ have such simple forms? (For instance, does it have anything to do with the memoryless property of the exponential distribution?)

Answer (score 1):

Start with a Poisson process $\Pi$ of rate $a+b$ on $(0,\infty)$. Paint each point of the Poisson process either red (with probability $a/(a+b)$) or green (with probability $b/(a+b)$), the colors being i.i.d. and independent of the locations of the points themselves. Let $X:=\min\{t\in\Pi: t$ is painted red$\}$ and
$Y:=\min\{t\in\Pi: t$ is painted green$\}$. Clearly $Z=\min(X,Y)$ is the first point of $\Pi$, and so has the exponential distribution with parameter $a+b$. Moreover, the color of that first point is red (in which case $Z=X$) with probability $a/(a+b)$, and therefore
$$
a/(a+b)=P(\hbox{first point is red})=P(Z=X)=P(X<Y).
$$
Of course the red points of $\Pi$ constitute a Poisson process of rate $(a+b)\cdot a/(a+b) = a$, so $X$ has the exponential distribution with parameter $a$. Likewise for $Y$.